# Excel sum cells with function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell value like 100/20. I mean this text equals "5". I want to calculate each cell and get sum on bottom.

I calculate a cell like this (just for a cell)

```
=LEFT( V342;FIND( "/"; V342 ) - 1 ) / RIGHT( V342; LEN( V342) - FIND( "/"; V342 ) )
```

How can i calculate and sum all cells ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like :

[image]

In **A1** through **A3**, in another cell enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(A1:A3,FIND("/",A1:A3,1)-1)/(MID(A1:A3,FIND("/",A1:A3,1)+1,9999)))
```

[image]

In your *locale* use **;** rather than **,**

Answer (score 2):

You can use array version of `SUM` (confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=SUM(LEFT(A1:A6, FIND("/",A1:A6,1)-1) / (MID(A1:A6, FIND("/",A1:A6,1)+1,50000)))
```

Or `SUMPRODUCT` confirmed with <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A1:A6, FIND("/",A1:A6,1)-1) / (MID(A1:A6, FIND("/",A1:A6,1)+1,50000)))
```